# Size of attachments in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to limit the size of attachments for work items in TFS 2010? Does this have to be done programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to programmatically change it. It can be done from IIS. 
This is to change the size of attachment to your required value for workItems in TFS 2010 for each collection individually. 
You must be a TFS Admin to do this.

Browse to

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/<Collection>/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx
```

You’ll see 3 asmx services – GetMaxAttachmentSize, GetWorkItemTrackingVersion and SetMaxAttachmentSize. 
Choose SetMaxAttachmentSize option and fill in the value of your choice. 
Restart of IIS server is not required, but I would recommend it, just to be sure.